# join a column by comparing two other columns in different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with different sizes:

df1:

```py
    id  datetime
0   a1  1/1/2015

1   a1  2/1/2015

2   a1  3/1/2015

3   a2  1/1/2015

4   a2  2/1/2015

5   a3  2/1/2015

6   a3  3/1/2015
```

df2:

```
    id  datetime    total cost

0   a1  1/1/2015    3

1   a1  2/1/2015    4

2   a1  3/1/2015    2.5

3   a2  1/1/2015    5

4   a2  2/1/2015    4

5   a2  3/1/2015    3

6   a3  1/1/2015    7

7   a3  2/1/2015    8

8   a3  3/1/2015    4
```

I want to compare df1 with df2 so that I can update my df1 with the total cost values for the corresponding id and datetime. So I want my result to look like:
df1:

```
    id  datetime    totalcost

0   a1  1/1/2015    3

1   a1  2/1/2015    4

2   a1  3/1/2015    2.5

3   a2  1/1/2015    5

4   a2  2/1/2015    4

5   a3  2/1/2015    8

6   a3  3/1/2015    4
```

I tried to use isin, but I was unable to compare both id and date time column. Is there any elegant way to do this other than a for loop and comparing row by row? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a simple `merge` on 2 keys:

```
res = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['id', 'datetime'])

print(res)

   id  datetime  total
0  a1  1/1/2015    3.0
1  a1  2/1/2015    4.0
2  a1  3/1/2015    2.5
3  a2  1/1/2015    5.0
4  a2  2/1/2015    4.0
5  a3  2/1/2015    8.0
6  a3  3/1/2015    4.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I had posted these df as an example but my real datasets have many more columns and I just need one of them to be merged. Can we specify the one that needs to be merged?

Comment: A trick is to merge only on the columns by getting a subset of your dataframe. For example, the columns you want are `x` and `y`. You do this: `pd.merge(df1, df2[['id', 'datetime', 'x', 'y']], on=['id', 'datetime'])` EDIT: forgot to add the keys